# Stable outcomes of a dynamic process

Tags: markov-chain

Consider a variable $Y_t$ that evolves over time according to the fixed relation $Y_{t+1} = f(Y_t)$. Clearly, fixed points of $f$ are absorbing states of the process. To assess *stability*, we may now allow for small errors, i.e. $Y_{t+1} = f(Y_t) + \epsilon_t$ (I don't think it matters much exactly how $\epsilon_t$ is distributed, but we should assume it has zero mean). In that case, I believe that the stable points will depend on the slope of $f$. In particular, we need to ask whether the derivative of $f$ is greater or less than one (at various points).

**Question**: Can anyone refer me to texts that clarify the mathematics of such processes?

Comment 1: I know this kind of thing crops up in a bunch of areas of economics, e.g. in macroeconomics (think of the Solow model), growth theory (think of the S shape in 'Poor Economics'), and evolutionary game theory. References from these would be fine, but ideally I am looking for a relatively abstract treatment.

Comment 2: It may be helpful if I provide an example of what I am after. Let $f(Y) = Y^2$ and suppose that the initial value $Y_0$ is in $[0, 1]$. Then $Y_t \in [0, 1]$ for all $t > 0$. Moreover, the function has fixed points at $Y = 0$ and $Y = 1$; so if $Y_t$ somehow hits these points, it will get stuck there. Considering now the `perturbed' process, let's suppose that $Y_{t+1} = Y_t^2 + \epsilon_t$. Computing the derivative, $f'(Y) = 2Y$ and so the derivatives are $f'(0) = 0 < 1$ and $f'(1) = 2 > 1$. This suggests that, in some sense (to be clarified I hope!), the fixed point at $Y = 0$ is the stable one and where the process should generally end up.

Comment: Sounds like you want to study dynamic systems? This is a branch of mathematics.

Comment: Yes it is a maths question, but with plenty of economics applications. I guess I could post on Math SE if nobody has any ideas (though I'll wait a bit to see; I believe that this theory should be well known in various areas of econ).

Comment: You misunderstand, I was answering your question "*Can anyone refer me to texts that clarify the mathematics of such processes?*" You can find a description of the theory and some textbooks here: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamical_systems_theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamical_systems_theory)

Comment: The actual criterion for discrete-time stability is as you suspect: $|f'(Y^*)| < 1$.

Comment: Ah I see! Thanks for the link

Comment: I think what you're after is a contraction mapping. If $f$ is from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ then $\sup |f'(x)| < 1$ guarantees this as Giskard said.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. Though I also want to understand the dynamics of functions that have more than one fixed point.

Comment: Usually, one uses different criteria for what it means to be stable for a deterministic dynamical system.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Thanks; if you could point to these criteria, I would be very grateful. (I think the key phrase may be "Lyapunov stability"?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the dynamic system $Y_{t+1} = f(Y_t)$. In order to investigate the stability locally at $Y^\ast = f(Y^\ast)$ you can take a Taylor expansion of $Y_{t+1}$ around $Y^\ast$.
$$
\begin{align*}
&Y_{t+1} \approx f(Y^\ast) + f'(Y^\ast)(Y_{t} - Y^\ast),\\
\to &Y_{t+1} \approx Y^\ast + f'(Y^\ast) (Y_{t} - Y^\ast),\\
\to &Y_{t+1} - Y^\ast \approx f'(Y^\ast) (Y_t - Y^\ast)
\end{align*}
$$

[These lecture notes from Oded Galor](https://econwpa.ub.uni-muenchen.de/econ-wp/mac/papers/0409/0409011.pdf) seem quite complete.
So:
$$
(Y_t - Y^\ast) = (f'(Y^\ast))^t(Y_1 - Y^\ast) 
$$
Now if $|f'(Y^\ast)| < 1$ then this converges to zero. So $Y_t$ converges back to $Y^\ast$ after a (small) local deviation.